# System.getProperty("user.name") return same result on server and client

Tags: jakarta-ee

I'm developing a JEE application and I deployed it on a server using Apache on STS.

When access it, from a client machine, using the url http://server_ip_adress/my_app/ I'm having the user_name of the server not the client. What I want to have is the client's user_name.

My code :

```
<li>
<p style="font-size: 22px;" id="hello">
            Bienvenue<%=System.getProperty("user.name")%>
</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Note that community members (and moderators) take a dim view of both queue jumpers and content vandalisers. Please try to exercise patience, and remember that 99% of folks are here in their free time.

Answer (score 0):

The code runs on the server side, then obviously system.getProperty returns a property of server. You have to pass user as parameter (GET or POST). You may also think to a login page...